# How to handle multiple return types in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web controller single method?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    model = myMethod(loggedInUserName);

    if (model != null)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");// Just want to re-direct to Error Controller
    }
}
```

I need to handle the above scenario. Type `ActionResult` is not the correct type because I am using `RedirectToAction("Index", "Error")` also.

Any input would be helpful.

Best regards

Comment: Typo?  It looks like you simply forgot the `return` keyword in the `else` block.  Presumably the compiler is giving you an error for this?  (As an aside... the `else` is not needed here.  You can return the redirect result simply after the `if` block.)

Comment: You are correct. I just missed it. Working after a while on MVC....thanks brother